# Copy over lan : best way to segment copy?

Tags: bandwidth, copy, robocopy

I do not really know where to post my message. Networks or system or scripting, so ...
I have a requirement in my company. Here is the goal :

- Monthly I'll have to copy a package> 500MB on 25 computers on 25 different sites. (For this I have an automated script Robocopy that copies and checks)
- Of these 25 sites, customers (~ 30 per site) will retrieve the previously copied package.

My problem is to run the upload package for customers and avoid LAN overloading. I was thinking of doing a basic script (autoit or PS) deposited on the client, and at the client's initiative he will download the 500Mb package.
The problem is : If my 30 clients launch the script at the same time, the network will be down...

Do you have an idea that would allow me to « segment » the download package from the client ?
I see something like : the client will verify the server that has the package if it is not already send more than 5 clients ? Go to waiting list, and when the slot is available : the client can download the package...  but I do not see how ...

Any idea ? ;-)
Thanks !!

NB: The use of DFS-R is proscribed in my case ...
Kreg

Comment: "The use of DFS-R is PROSCRIBED in my case", did you mean PROHIBITED how about using BITS.

Comment: Yes prohibited sorry :)
BITS. Hum yes why not ! I check on google

Comment: It isn't the answer for your question, but haven't you thought about using BitTorrent to distribute the files to the clients?

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy has an option /IPG:x that can solve your problem. This option pauses the copy for x milisecords after every 64KB.

Which IPG value to use is dependend on your network speed and usage. If you have a fast network, you might want to test /ipg:100 (the copy is slowed down bij 13 minutes). On slower networks you might want to start with /ipg:1000 (2:15 hours delay).

I wrote an article once that probably will help you: http://zeda.nl/EN/Blog/001_Copy_files_on_slow_links